# How can I disable agent caching for the kubernetes Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am using the [kubernetes plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin) with Jenkins to automate my builds and am using the `BUILD_NUMBER` in my pipeline definition:

```
def TEST = "${env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger() % 5}"
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      label 'kind'
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: "$TEST"
spec:
...
```

however Jenkins seems to be caching the value of `TEST` templated into the agent YAML. I'm getting `name: 3` for multiple builds in a row for example.

Is it possible to disable this caching?